# Custom constructor function in Mongoose schema/models

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Greeting all!

I defined a Mongoose schema as below and registered a model (InventoryItemModel). Is there a way to create a custom constructor function for the schema, so that when I instantiate an object from the model, the function will be called (for example, to load the object with value from database)?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var InventoryItemSchema = new Schema({
    Sku : String
  , Quanity : Number
  , Description : String
  , Carted : []
  , CreatedDate  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
  , ModifiedDate  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});

mongoose.model('InventoryItem', InventoryItemSchema);

var item = new InventoryItem();
```

Can I add some custom constructor function so that the item will be populated from database upon instantiation?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, i wanted to create an inventory management. The above object represents an item. Some API will push item into the database, and in my program, I want the model to load one item from the database when I instantiate an object.

Comment: Take a look at Mongoose's support for [adding static constructor methods to models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics).

Answer (score 15):

Depending on the direction you want to take, you could:

**1) Use Hooks**

Hooks are automatically triggered when models init, validate, save, and remove.
This is the 'inside-out' solution.
You can check out the docs here:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

**2) Write a static creation function for your schema.**

Statics live on your model object and can be used to replace functionality like creating a new model. If you have extra logic for your `create` step, you can write it yourself in a static function. This is the 'outside-in' solution:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Comment: How do you exactly do #2 (static creation function)? There doesn't seem to be any examples in the Mongoose guide and just adding a `myschema.static.create` function doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: That link (#statics) shows you how to write statics. Just write your own static (createNew or something) that that goes through whatever logic you want it to go through upon creation.

Comment: Sorry, I confused methods with statics.

Comment: i did `2)` too, but I think the method shouldn't  be named  `create`, since it collides with [Model.create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create). Not sure if overriding the method is harmful, but it's safer to use another name, I guess (like `make`, `initialize`, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation of option #2 from `@hunterloftis`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229099/2476755).

> 2) Write a static creation function for your schema.

```
someSchema.statics.addItem = function addItem(item, callback){
//Do stuff (parse item)
 (new this(parsedItem)).save(callback);
}
```

When you want to create a new model from someSchema, instead of

```
var item = new ItemModel(itemObj);
item.save(function (err, model) { /* etc */ });
```

do this

```
ItemModel.addItem(itemObj, function (err, model) { /* etc */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem myself and wrote a mongoose plugin that'll help solve your problem

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , construct = require('mongoose-construct')

var user = new Schema({})
user.plugin(construct)

user.pre('construct', function(next){
    console.log('Constructor called...')
    next()
})

var User = mongoose.model('User', user)
var myUser = new User(); // construct hook will be called
```

Here's the repo (it's also available on npm): https://github.com/IlskenLabs/mongoose-construct

Comment: This is a slick idea. Can it capture the argument passed to the schema constructor though? For instance, if I wanted to call `var myUser = new User({foo:'bar'})` to configure some property of the user at creation, is there any way to access that 'foo' from within your pre-construct function?

Comment: @Victorb I'll be honest I don't even remember how this works anymore and seriously doubt it works with the latest versions of mongoose. Sorry!

Comment: @Victorb Looked it over, sorry it doesn't look like that'd be possible with any hook without breaking stuff. I'd make a wrapper class that takes the arguments and initializes a mongoose model under the hood

Answer (score 0):

@hunterloftis provided me the answer I needed.  Now, nearly 6+ years later, here is my solution for anyone else.

```
InventoryItemSchema.static( 'new', function( that )
{
    let instance = new InventoryItemSchema();
    Object.assign( instance, that );
    return instance;
});
```

or as the one-liner (which is less conducive to debugging)

```
InventoryItemSchema.static( 'new', function( that )
{return Object.assign( new InventoryItemSchema(), that );});
```

Either way, where you would like to have

```
let inventoryItem = new InventoryItemSchema({...});
```

you will instead have

```
let inventoryItem = InventoryItemSchema.new({...});
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to export. Here is an example:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let  Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let restaurentSchema = new Schema({
  name : String
})

//export

module.exports = mongoose.model("Restaurent", restaurentSchema)
```