# MongoDB - I want to specify a primary key and operate it with name other than `_id`

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose, primary-key, objectid

I had a **Tag** schema (defined with mongoose):

```
var Tag = new Schema({
  _id: String  // Not ObjectId but the name of the tag.
});
```

I want to use the tag name as its `_id`, but I don't want to **operate** this field with name `_id`. For example, I would like to add a new tag with code `new Tag({name: 'tagA'})` instead of `new Tag({_id: 'tagA'})`. Since the code is more expressive in this way.

So I need to change `name` to `_id`. One method would be using the **pre-save hook**.

```
Tag.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this._id && this.name) this._id = this.name;
  next();
});
```

Are there ways better than this one?

Comment: Remember that the `_id` cannot be changed once the document is created. I generally try to avoid strings that might need to be renamed as the document `_id`.

Comment: That being said, I think your solution is reasonable. There are a few options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217067/custom-constructor-function-in-mongoose-schema-models

Comment: In firsts glance, specifying name as the primary key is ok. But in this way the code will be less expressive. Also I am using Backbone.js, consider the following code `var tag = new Tag({_id:'tag name'}); tag.save();`, the save call will launch a **PUT** req instead of POST, because the `_id` exists. So I decide to store both _id and name, where _id is the original ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best option I found with mongoose for implementing custom primary keys.

```
<schemaToHook>.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
   // trigger next middleware in parallel
   next();
   if (!this._id && this.name) {
       this._id = this.name;
   }
   done();
 });
```

I am using a parallel middleware and expecting better performance. Also, while using the above implementation you might want to consider using `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert = true` for `INSERT` or `REPLACE` equivalent implementation.

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {foo: 'bar'}, // find a document with that filter
    modelDoc, // document to insert when nothing was found
    {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}, // options
    function (err, doc) { // callback
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // handle document
        }
    }
);
```